# F# as a Scripting Language

Tags: .net, scripting, f#

Is there a good way to write F# scripts that execute stand-alone without compiling?
...As scripts that could be executed via task scheduler on a server? I assume the server would have the core F# libraries, but not Visual Studio installed.

Is there an F# equivalent to [CS-Script](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/cs-script_for_cp.aspx) or [NScript](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/nscript.aspx),
 but not a hack (workaround).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
fsi --exec
```

will run all the files on the command line through the interactive console then exit.

Comment: And http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=61ad6924-93ad-48dc-8c67-60f7e7803d3c&displaylang=en  
will install fine on a server without VS2008 installed?

Comment: Yes, there's also a zip distrib in case you want to install under linux or just don't wan't to use an msi.

Comment: just more info, http://blogs.msdn.com/chrsmith/archive/2008/09/12/scripting-in-f.aspx